# Uploads multiples images with multiples files field

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, busboy

I'm having hard time for the last few day on how to upload multiples images on firebase with busboy.
I want to use 3 fields with 3 different images. so I can store it in one folder.
I also want the image to have the field name

I found one topic that helped me use Promise.all and forEach but it didn't worked out for me

- storing all files in an array

```
    var Promise = require('promise');
    const Busboy = require("busboy");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const os = require("os");
    const path = require("path");


    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    let imageToAdd = {};
    let imagesToUpload = []
    let newFileName;

    busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        const imageExtension =  filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];
        filename = `${fieldname}.${imageExtension} `
        newFileName = filename
        const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
        imageToAdd = { file: filepath, type: mimetype };
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
        imagesToUpload = [...imagesToUpload, imageToAdd]
    });
```

- loop over the files array and store the promises in a new array
- then wait all the promise to resolve with Promise.all

```
    busboy.on("finish", () => {
        let promises = []
        imagesToUpload.forEach((imageToBeUploaded) => {
            promises.push(
                admin
                .storage()
                .bucket(`${config.storageBucket}`)
                .upload(imageToBeUploaded.file, {
                    resumable: false,
                    destination: `projectname/${newFileName}`,
                    metadata: {
                        metadata: {
                          contentType: imageToBeUploaded.type,
                        }
                    }
                })          
            )     

        }) 
        Promise.all(promises)
        .then(res => { 
            res.status(200).json({msg: 'Successfully uploaded all images')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({error: err.code})
        })
    })
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
})
```

Only the last image is stored in my firebase storage.

Is someone can help me with this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one `newFileName` in your code, while you have an array of `imagesToUpload`. So you're uploading each of those images to the same `newFileName` and end up with whichever of the uploads completes last.

You'll want to keep an array of `newFileNames`, to match up with the array of `imagesToUpload`.

Something like:

```
const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
let imageToAdd = {};
let imagesToUpload = []
let newFileNames = [];

busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    const imageExtension =  filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];
    filename = `${fieldname}.${imageExtension} `
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
    imageToAdd = { file: filepath, type: mimetype };
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

    imagesToUpload.push(imageToAdd);
    newFileNames.push(filename);
});

...

busboy.on("finish", () => {
    let promises = imagesToUpload.map((imageToBeUploaded, index) => {
        admin
        .storage()
        .bucket(`${config.storageBucket}`)
        .upload(imageToBeUploaded.file, {
            resumable: false,
            destination: `projectname/${newFileNames[index]}`,
            metadata: {
                metadata: {
                  contentType: imageToBeUploaded.type,
                }
            }
        })          
    }) 
    Promise.all(promises)
      ...
```

Comment: it worked ! thanks you so much for your quick answer.